# Can I use ipython as my chosen interpreter in devsim?

Tags: python

I've downloaded the binaries [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/devsim/files/20131222/) for devsim for ubuntu.

If you go to the `bin` folder there is an executable called `devsim` which basically seems like a python interpreter with the devsim module preloaded as `ds`. What I would like is instead of dropping into an python interpreter dropping into an ipython one.

Is this an easy thing to do? I tried thigs like:

```
ipython devsim
```

but gave me an error. I also tried running `ipython` and attempted to import `devsim` which also failed.

To be honest I had low hopes that the above two tricks would work. Any advice guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is inspired by the answer given by Juan. I thought of editing his answer but then this evolved a lot so decided to keep it separately.

Some of the steps below will require root access and assume a *nix based system.

1. Create a file with the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   /path/to/executable/devsim /usr/bin/ipython "$@"
   ```
2. Save the file as `/usr/bin/devsim`
3. Make it executable by running `chmod uoa+x /usr/bin/devsim`

Now whenever you type `devsim` at the command prompt you'll be dropped into an ipython session. To access the devsim module you simply do:

3. `import ds` or `from ds import *`

depending on your preference.

Comment: What linux version are you using.  The /usr/bin/ipython on my system (ubuntu 12.04) is different.  It calls IPython.frontend.terminal.ipapp.launch_new_instance()

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 and using IPython 2.3.1 (installed through pip) http://ipython.org/install.html

Answer (score 1):

/usr/bin/ipython is a python script.  Devsim starts its own embedded python 2.7 interpreter.

On my ubuntu 12.04 system, the following works for me:

`devsim /usr/bin/ipython`

The devsim packages currently online are for ubuntu 12.04.  If you need any help getting it to work for your system, please file a ticket at http://www.github.com/devsim/devsim.

Comment: Hey juan I've created an answer below, do you think you could merge that to yours so I can accept yours as answered? I tried editing but someone rejected them or I'm not doing something right

Comment: You may have to wait 48 hours to accept your own answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer